# Using field mappings to remove fields from merged table using ArcMap

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, arcgis-10.1, table, field-mapping

I'm trying to combine a (large) number of tables into a merged table, keeping only certain fields. I've tried the below, but it still gives all the fields.

Any ideas?

```
listEventTables = arcpy.ListTables("RS_EVENT_ALL_*")

fieldMappings = arcpy.FieldMappings()

for table in listEventTables:
    fieldMappings.addTable(table)

for field in fieldMappings.fields:
    if field.name not in ["ROUTE_ID","TRIP_NUM","OFFICE_ID","VOLUME","ACTIVITY","ARRIV_TIME"]:
    fieldMappings.removeFieldMap(fieldMappings.findFieldMapIndex(field.name))

eventTable = outGDB + "Merge" # Merge of event tables (has to be in a GDB)

arcpy.Merge_management(listEventTables, eventTable, fieldMappings)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure why that isn't working for you, but why not try an additive approach instead of a removal approach (see code below).  I confess I haven't tested this code to make sure it will work, but I'm pretty sure it will.

I've tested this script out on a test dataset and it works fine.

I've tested out a simplified variant of your original script step-by-step to see where it was failing, and I couldn't find anything wrong with the procedure.  My one thought is that it appears that your `fieldmappings.removeFieldMap()` statement isn't properly indented.  However, if that's the case in the script you are running, it should simply throw an error.

```
fieldList = ["ROUTE_ID","TRIP_NUM","OFFICE_ID","VOLUME","ACTIVITY","ARRIV_TIME"]

listEventTables = arcpy.ListTables("RS_EVENT_ALL_*")

fieldMappings = arcpy.FieldMappings()

#iterate through fields and create unique fieldmap for each
for field in fieldList:
    
    #creates a fieldmap with name of input field
    vars()[field] = arcpy.FieldMap()
        
    for table in listEventTables:
        vars()[field].addInputField(table,field)

    outField = vars()[field].outputField
    outField.name = field
    vars()[field].outputField = outField

    fieldMappings.addFieldMap(vars()[field])

    
eventTable = outGDB + "Merge" # Merge of event tables (has to be in a GDB)

arcpy.Merge_management(listEventTables, eventTable, fieldMappings)
```